# How to declare class in other file and then import it in JS?

Tags: javascript, class, import, module, export

I'm trying to declare class in other file and and import it as module but i get error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

this is what i have already tried:

file1.js

```
class List{
...
} 
export default List;
```

file2.js

```
import List from 'file1'
let x = new List();
```

Comment: try `import List from './file1'`

Comment: `./file1` if the two in same folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export and import class properly in javascript ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46224687/how-to-export-and-import-class-properly-in-javascript-es6)

Comment: @NikitaUmnov that will not help. OP if this is in a browser, you have to make sure your `<script>` has `type=module`

Comment: @manoj the title is promising, the answer is not.

Comment: @Pointy <script> which refer to file1.js already have type=module attribute.

Comment: You need `type=module` for any `<script>` that uses either `import` or `export`.

Comment: @Pointy after adding type=mode to file2's <script> i started to get such an error Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "file1". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../". so i added ./ before file1 and now i get something like this " GET http://localhost:63342/ToDoList/item 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: Well that means that the files are not installed on the server where you think they are.